# karaf Accessing resources inside webinf folder

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

I have deployed a webbundle in karaf. In the web-inf folder i have kept some files. is there a way to access those using absolute path. Or do i need to keep the reources in karaf deploy folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no absolute path for resources deployed in a osgi environment as those resources aren't "unziped" to a working directory. 
So yes you need to access these resources via the bundle context classloader. 
Or keep those resources outside of your bundle, this is completely dependent on your use-case.

Comment: In the case of a web bundle, will the bundle context classloader find resources in /WEB-INF or do they have to reside in /WEB-INF/classes? I guess the latter?

Comment: depends on how you configure your classpath in the webbundle, but /WEB-INF should already be accessible.